# Change variable from another scope without using global?

Tags: python

I am new to Python.

How can I accomplish something like this:

```
def gameon():
  currentNum = 0
  for x in range(100):
    currentNum+=1
    otherfunc()

def otherfunc(maybe a possible parameter...):
  for y in range(500):
    #check for some condition is true and if it is... 
    #currentNumFROMgameon+=1
```

My actual code that used global variables:

```
def gameon():
  global currentNum
  currentNum = 0
  for x in range(100):
    currentNum+=1
    otherfunc()

def otherfunc():
  global currentNum
  for y in range(500):
    if(...):
      currentNum+=1
global currentNum
```

How can I accomplish this(accessing and changing `currentNum` from `otherfunc`) without making `currentNum` global?

Comment: Have you tried passing  `currentNum` to the function and let the function return the modified version of `currentNum`?

Comment: @araknoid ahh that works, thanks. But what if it should go through a function with a purpose of returning true or false based on some conditions but it would also have to increment "currentNum"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have access to `currentNum` in `otherfunc` you should pass it to that function. If you want `otherfunc` to change it, simply have it return an updated version. Try this code:

```
def gameon():
  currentNum = 0
  for x in range(100):
    currentNum+=1
    currentNum = otherfunc(currentNum)

def otherfunc(currentNumFROMgameon):
  for y in range(500):
    if True: # check your condition here, right now it's always true
      currentNumFROMgameon+=1
  return currentNumFROMgameon
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if it should go through a function with a purpose of returning true or false based on some conditions but it would also have to increment "currentNum"?

Comment: @overso You could write a separate function that returns True or False. That function will have to receive whatever it needs as input variables. Though generally if such a check is simple enough, it's easier to just check it in an if statement rather than write a separate function for it.